# Custom UI control for Android and IOS using C#

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.android

I've just started looking at how I can generate and port applications to Android and IOS, I've started to look at Xamarin. First, I'm looking to generate custom UI control of a 10x10 Matrix (checkerboard - each square is a different colour) with each square being able to be selected and a specific image being displayed.

After looking at the documents and looking at MVVM examples, I'm not entirely sure what the best method of doing this : How should I structure the code (should I use just SVG drawing) or is there a better method of doing this in Android and IOS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest I would start with Xamarin Forms and create a grid control with 10x10 image buttons. This way you get the event handling built-in. This would work for iOS, Android & Windows Phone out of the box. From there you could evolve it to more native specific code if necessary.

If you want to control the look pixel perfect then creating native custom rendered views would be the option but this is much more work of course so I would not start there. On Android you would subclass from ***Android.Widget.View*** and on iOS you would do it from ***MonoTouch.UIKit.UIView***. For both you would override the *Draw* method.